# coq: push a function into a pattern matching

Tags: coq

We have a function f.

```
f : nat -> nat
```

If we apply f to a pattern matching like this,

```
f match n with
  | O => O
  | S n' => n'
  end
```

how can we rewrite it as follows?

```
match n with
| O => f O
| S n' => f n'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest is to use the `case` tactic.

```
Lemma lift_match : forall (f : nat -> nat) (n : nat),
    (f match n with
       | O => O
       | S n' => n'
       end) = 
    (match n with
     | O => f O
     | S n' => f n'
     end).
Proof.
  intros f n.
  case n; auto.
Qed.
```

Also, if you define the above lemma you can use it in your proofs as `rewrite lift_match`.

Comment: If you want an in-place solution you can use `replace (f match...) with (match ...) by (case n; auto).`.